# Upload XML data to MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-error-1064

I have a VOIP website http://www.dialncall.com/. The calling rates are changed each month. I just build a CMS to change rates. In that system I need to change rate of every country one by one. It's hard to do because country list so BIG.
I can get the rate list as XML file. Could any one tell to me how to upload to MySQL table. 
below image is screen print of the XML file

[image: XLS contents]

Comment: @ Bojan Kogoj  I need to the code to update or upload to MySQL

Comment: what does that have to do with mysql-error? Also if you show your XML structure someone could help

Comment: @ Bojan Kogoj 
I need to know how to upload this XML to MySQL

Comment: You cannot upload it directly. There is some "mode" in phpMyAdmin but I've never tried it, and it probably needs quite specific XML. So if you give us your XML structure and database tables we can help you how to do it. Other then that I'm clueless

Comment: @Bojan Kogo 
the image is XML structure.

if u wanna download it.
here is the link [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkwPlJliFrZWdGFtMzZkdjJoZ2ZmcWJHLU1nQmFydFE&hl=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
[Class: MySQL to XML - XML to MySQL](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/782-PHP-Insert-XML-in-MySQL-and-export-MySQL-to-XML.html)